# Suma de n números

Tags: python

¿Qué modificación a mi código se pueda realizar para que solo me indique el valor de la suma sucesiva de n números y no el resultado de cada iteración? Por ejemplo, al escribir en la consola suma(5) me muestra:
1
3
6
10
15

Sin embargo, quiero que solo me indique el último valor, en este caso, 15.

```
def suma(n):
suma_total = 0


for i in range(1, n + 1):
    suma_total = suma_total + i
    print(suma_total)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo saca el `print` del bloque del `for`

```
def suma(n): 
        suma_total = 0
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            suma_total = suma_total + i
        print(suma_total)
suma(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa:

```
def suma(n):
  suma_total = sum([i for i in range(1, n + 1)])
  print(suma_total)

suma(5)
```

Comment: No hace falta una comprension de lista para sumar todos los numeros de un rango, pero buena idea de todos modos!

Answer (score 0):

Se que esto no responde a la pregunta, pero viendo que alguien ya dio una respuesta con una forma alternativa y mi forma también da la suma del rango lo diré de todos modos.

Sumar los numeros de un rango, sea con sum o con un bucle for, puede ser un proceso muy lento para rangos de muchos numeros, como `range(0, 1000000, 1)`:

```
from timeit import timeit

r = range(10**6) #1000000 en notacion cientifica
timeit(lambda:sum(r), number=1)
```

Produce: 0.072702563

El objeto range en realidad representa una especie de [progresion aritmetica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progresi%C3%B3n_aritm%C3%A9tica). Y existe una formula para obtener la suma de una cantidad n de terminos de la progresion aritmetica.

La formula sería `n(a1+an)/2`
Donde n es la cantidad de terminos a sumar, a1 es el primer termino y an es el ultimo termino a sumar.

De esta formula se puede obtener la formula que imita a sum(r) donde r es un rango no vacio:
`len(r)*(r[0]+r[-1])/2`

Para rangos vacíos, la suma va a ser 0.

A partir de todas estas conclusiones, podemos crear una función que devuelva la suma de los numeros de un range:

```
def sum_range_numbers(r):
    if(r):
        # Si el rango NO está vacío
        return (r[0] + r[-1])*len(r)//2
    else:
        # Si el rango está vacío
        return 0
```

Ahora vamos a probar con 10 numeros grandes aleatorios cuanto tiempo tarda cada forma:

def sum_range_numbers(r):
if(r):
# Si el rango NO está vacío
return (r[0] + r[-1])*len(r)//2
else:
# Si el rango está vacío
return 0

```
from timeit import timeit
import random

for _ in range(10):
    r = range(random.randint(-10**6, 0), random.randint(0, 10**6), random.randint(1, 10))

    print(r)
    print("sum(r) (Milisegundos):", timeit(lambda:sum(r), number=1)*1000, "resultado: ", sum(r))
    print("sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos):", timeit(lambda:sum_range_numbers(r), number=1)*1000, "resultado:", sum_range_numbers(r))
    print()
```

Produce:

```
range(-939432, 823896, 8)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 15.888838999999988 resultado:  -12733873152
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.004965999999995141 resultado: -12733873152

range(-60179, 212950, 6)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 1.875858000000008 resultado:  3477152448
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.005296999999959695 resultado: 3477152448

range(-199467, 984066, 5)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 16.84100399999999 resultado:  92859682686
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.004965999999995141 resultado: 92859682686

range(-1492, 689019, 8)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 5.611019999999966 resultado:  29671300640
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.005297000000070717 resultado: 29671300640

range(-480991, 119506, 6)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 7.22864099999998 resultado:  -18089501835
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.005296999999959695 resultado: -18089501835

range(-484825, 961034, 8)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 13.096573 resultado:  43033069499
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.004965999999995141 resultado: 43033069499

range(-128708, 490688, 8)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 4.021209000000026 resultado:  14012995900
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.004965999999995141 resultado: 14012995900

range(-508550, 520941, 10)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 7.30909099999999 resultado:  637775250
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.004965999999995141 resultado: 637775250

range(-600789, 741611, 4)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 24.135195999999915 resultado:  23629260400
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.0056280000000352715 resultado: 23629260400

range(-63377, 155444, 7)
sum(r) (Milisegundos): 1.1028029999999855 resultado:  1439037613
sum_range_numbers(r) (Milisegundos): 0.004967000000077881 resultado: 1439037613
```